# Running Heroku CLI commands through a python script

Tags: python, heroku, heroku-cli

I am looking to run commands I typically would run through Heroku CLI via a python script, namely:

```
heroku pg:backups:capture
```

Historically, for running Heroku commands in Python I have used [Heroku3.py](https://github.com/martyzz1/heroku3.py), which works for me for things like restarting dynos.  I am having difficulty finding a way to execute commands for addons, such as the one listed above.

Is there a way to call CLI commands through python?

Comment: The Heroku CLI commands are no different than any other command-line / shell commands. So the solutions here should solve your problem: [How to execute a program or call a system command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command). Unless you already tried those but are failing, in that case, you'll need to clarify what _specifically_ is the "difficulty" you are facing.

Comment: ...or if you need to also capture the output: [Running shell command and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4760215/2745495)

Comment: ...or you can reimplement Heroku3.py yourself by calling [Heroku's REST APIs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference)